# Fetching Accelerometer Value in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to store accelerometer X, Y, Z value in a Text File but I am getting run time error, after some of seconds similar value start inserting in the file.

Simple GUI
[image]

[image: Android Apps]

TextArea Showing Text File Values.

**Now code is here, Please can some one tell me where I am doing mistake or what change i should do in code?**
Thanks

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener 
{

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
TextView title,tvx,tvy,tvz;
EditText etshowval;
RelativeLayout layout;
private String acc;
private String read_str = "";
private final String filepath = "/sdcard/acc.txt";
private BufferedWriter mBufferedWriter;
private BufferedReader mBufferedReader;
private float x;
private float y;
private float z;

public static final int MSG_DONE = 1;
public static final int MSG_ERROR = 2;
public static final int MSG_STOP = 3;

private boolean mrunning;
private Handler mHandler;
private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;

private Handler uiHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){ 
        String str = (String) msg.obj;
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case MSG_DONE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MSG_ERROR: 
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),str,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MSG_STOP:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            default:
                break;
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    //get layout
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

    //get textviews
    title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);   
    tvx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xval);
    tvy = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yval);
    tvz = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zval);
    etshowval = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.showval);
    title.setText("Accelerator");

    mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("Working Thread");
    mHandlerThread.start();

    mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
    mHandler.post(r);
}

private Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (mrunning)
            {
                Message msg1 = new Message();
                try 
                {
                    WriteFile(filepath,acc);
                    msg1.what = MSG_DONE;
                    msg1.obj = "Start to write to SD 'acc.txt'";
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    msg1.what = MSG_ERROR;
                    msg1.obj = e.getMessage();
                }
                uiHandler.sendMessage(msg1);
            }
            else
            {   
                Message msg2 = new Message();
                msg2.what = MSG_STOP;
                msg2.obj = "Stop to write to SD 'acc.txt'";
                uiHandler.sendMessage(msg2);
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

public void onStartClick(View view) 
{
    start();
}

public void onStopClick(View view) 
{
    stop();
}

public void onReadClick(View view) 
{
    etshowval.setText(ReadFile(filepath));
}

private synchronized void start()
{
    mrunning = true;
}

private synchronized void stop()
{
    mrunning = false;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) 
{
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) 
    {
        x = sensorEvent.values[0]; 
        y = sensorEvent.values[1]; 
        z = sensorEvent.values[2]; 
        acc= String.valueOf(x) + ", " + String.valueOf(y) + ", " + String.valueOf(z);

        tvx.setText("X = "+ String.valueOf(x));
        tvy.setText("Y = "+ String.valueOf(y));
        tvz.setText("Z = "+ String.valueOf(z));
    }
  }

  public void CreateFile(String path)
  {
    File f = new File(path);
    try {
        Log.d("ACTIVITY", "Create a File.");
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public String ReadFile (String filepath)
  {
    mBufferedReader = null;
    String tmp = null;

    if (!FileIsExist(filepath))
        CreateFile(filepath);

    try 
    {
        mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
        // Read string
        while ((tmp = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            tmp += "\n";
            read_str += tmp;
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return read_str;
  }

   public void WriteFile(String filepath, String str)
   {
    mBufferedWriter = null;

    if (!FileIsExist(filepath))
        CreateFile(filepath);

    try 
    {
        mBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepath, true));
        mBufferedWriter.write(str);
        mBufferedWriter.newLine();
        mBufferedWriter.flush();
        mBufferedWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

   public boolean FileIsExist(String filepath)
   {
    File f = new File(filepath);

    if (! f.exists())
    {
        Log.e("ACTIVITY", "File does not exist.");
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
   }

    @Override
   protected void onPause()
   {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Unregister accelerometerListener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onPause();
   } 
  }
```

Comment: Can you attach logcat output with the error you mentioned?

Comment: "Accelerator" in the UI should really be "Accelerometer".

Comment: WriteFile() is called within the inner loop of a Runnable. However, WriteFile() creates a new BufferedWriter() with each call. You should move the call to `new BufferedWriter()` outside of WriteFile.

Comment: @Michcael just now using LogCat app i got 1 text file of logcat, you want to see that?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 you are talking about "New Bufferedwriter" that is inside the "public void WriteFile(String filepath, String str)"

Comment: @ManishKumar: yes, that one.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Still i am getting same problem, can you give me your mail id, I am sending you whole project  code. if you have time can you check once.